# How to test a writeonly property

Tags: rhino-mocks

In my application, using MVP pattern, presenter is setting some properties on view.For example, Iview has string Customer {set;}.Now, I want to test that this property was set with some value "x".How can I do the test with rhino mocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't define write-only properties. As the [.NET design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) say:

> Do not provide set-only properties.
>
> If the property getter cannot be provided, use a method to implement the functionality instead. The method name should begin with Set followed by what would have been the property name. For example, AppDomain has a method called SetCachePath instead of having a set-only property called CachePath.

In most cases, defining a read/write property is much easier, and it makes it a breeze to unit testi the owning type. You wouldn't need Rhino Mocks for that, as you can simply read the value directly from the property.

However, if you rather want a mutating method as described in the design guidelines, you must make it `virtual` to be able to use Rhino Mocks to verify that it was correctly called. Although this is certainly possible, it's more complicated to set up, so I would only take that route if there were compelling reasons to do so.